# How to intialize a service globally and export to be used by other modules in svelte js

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to integrate [mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com) in my svelte project. To intializae mixpanel instance i need to do something like :

```
import {mixpanel} from 'mixpanel-browser'

mixpanel.init('TOKEN', {options});

// and then can use it's functions like 

mixpanel.track('user_Action')
mixapnel.identify('...')
```

Doing it for every file doesn't seem to be a good idea but how do i do it in svelte ? like instantiate this at one place and then use it everywhere else ?

Answer (score 1):

Initialize mixpanel in the root [+layout.js](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#layout-layout-js) and return it as a layout data prop.

All children of the layout can access parent layout data props as part of their PageData props.

Answer (score 1):

In `+layout.js` put

```
import { PUBLIC_MIXPANEL_TOKEN } from "$env/static/public";
import mixpanel from 'mixpanel-browser';

mixpanel.init(PUBLIC_MIXPANEL_TOKEN, { debug: true });
```

In the page which you want to track e.g. `+page.svelte`

```
import mixpanel from "mixpanel-browser";

onMount(() => {
    mixpanel.track("HomePage", { name: 'Alok' });
});
```